# Tables in LyX: too much vertical space in cell with fixed column width and wrapped text

Tags: tables, lyx, vertical

In a cell with fixed column width and wrapped text in a table - the table is generated entirely in LyX, rather than LaTeX - there is too much vertical space in that cell. Image below; problem highlighted in yellow. Does anyone have any thoughts on how to deal with this? I've tried line spacing (single) and modifying the height of the cell (impossible).

(My LyX tables are quite pretty now - thanks mostly to the expertise of everyone on this forum - but this issue is still bothering me.)

[image: Table example - too much vertical space in final row]

Edit: this is what LaTeX is apparently doing in the background:

```
\begin{singlespace}
\noindent \begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{lc}
\toprule 
\textbf{Test XYZ} & \textbf{p-value}\tabularnewline
\midrule
Statistic A & 0.00\tabularnewline
Statistic B & 0.00\tabularnewline
Statistic C & 0.00\tabularnewline
\midrule
\multicolumn{2}{>{\raggedright}p{0.75\textwidth}}{\begin{singlespace}
\noindent \raggedright{}\textcolor{black}{\footnotesize{}Lorem ipsum
dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec mollis est libero,
sed vehicula erat tempor eget. Morbi justo justo, mattis ut elit tristique,
iaculis ornare sapien. Nulla tristique eros id justo pulvinar lacinia. }
\end{singlespace}
}\tabularnewline
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\par\end{center}
\end{singlespace}
```

Thanks a million!

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Could you post a full compilable code for this table?

Comment: @Bernard This is fully generated in LyX -- i.e. Insert Table etc.; then a right-click into the cell the width of which I want to fix, and so on. I can add a Lyx file rather than code?

Comment: No idea. I don't know Lyx, so I can't help in this respect, but the reason for this unwanted spacing lies in the LaTeX code which is behind.

Comment: @Bernard I've added the LaTeX code

Comment: @oceansize:  The unwanted vertical white space is caused by the `singlespace` environment inside the `multicolumn`.

Comment: I'd think  the repeated `singlespace` environment inside the `\multicolumn` of the last row adds this spurious vertical spacing. You should safely remove it.

Comment: @leandriis & Bernard you're my heroes - that deals with it. How simple! Thanks a trillion!

Comment: @Bernard Can I somehow mark this question as answered?

Comment: @oceansize welcome to TeX SX! +1 for your nice screenshot and for being responsive to follow-up questions. I have some picky advice that will help your future posts. 1. Yes, you can post a .lyx file since it is just a text file. See here: https://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/MinimalExample. 2. Note that Bernard asked for a *full* compilable example. You only posted the code for the table. Next time, please post a full .tex file, starting with e.g. `\begin{document}` and ending with `\end{document}`. I look forward to your next questions! Note also that you might fund the lyx-users mailing list helpful.

Comment: @oceansize and most importantly, can you please file a bug/enhancement ticket for LyX? I would like to fix this issue in LyX if it is a bug, so that others do not come across the same issue. To do this, go to https://www.lyx.org/trac. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The extra vertical white space is caused by the `singlespace` environment inside the `multicolumn` command. You can safely remove this environment to obtian the following output:

[image]